# When using requests.session to login www.researchgate.net, I got a "403 Forbidden", warning that "Your browser doesn't accept cookies. "

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm coding a web crawler for https://www.reseachgate.net with python. When I try to login using requests.Session, I got a "403 Forbidden" page, warning that "Your browser doesn't accept cookies. Cookies are required to use this site." How to solve this problem?

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoupter 

headers = {
            'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'
        }
session = requests.Session()

params = {'login': '######@std.uestc.edu.cn', 'password': '#######'}
s = session.post("https://www.researchgate.net/application.Login.html", data = params, headers = headers)
print s.cookies.get_dict()
print s.text
s = session.get("https://www.researchgate.net/home")
print BeautifulSoup(s.text).title
```

Here's what I got:

```
 <div class="error-page">
     <h1>
         403 Forbidden            </h1>

     <h3>Your browser doesn't accept cookies. Cookies are required to use this site.</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I missed some fields in my login form.

Here's my updated code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
loginpage = session.get("https://www.researchgate.net/application.Login.html")
request_token = BeautifulSoup(loginpage.text).form.find("input",{"name":"request_token"}).attrs["value"]
print request_token
params = {"request_token":request_token,
          "invalidPasswordCount":"0",
          'login': 'my_email', 
          'password': 'my_password',
          "setLoginCookie":"yes"
          }
session.post("https://www.researchgate.net/application.Login.html", data = params)
s = session.get("https://www.researchgate.net/search.Search.html?type=researcher&query=zhang")
print BeautifulSoup(s.text).title
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `Scrapy`.

Ref: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html

Here is a simple example,

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest

class MySpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'researchgatespider'
    allowed_domains = ['researchgate.net']
    login_page = 'http://www.researchgate.net/login'   # replace the valid URL 

        def init_request(self):
         #This function is called before crawling starts.
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'name': 'userrname', 'password': 'password'},
                    callback=self.isValid_login)

    def isValid_login(self, response):
        if "XXXXXXX - term to check" in response.body:
            self.log("Successfully logged in")
            self.initialized()
        else:
            self.log("Wrong credentials")


    def parse_item(self, response):
           # write XPATH / any type of extraction here.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried Scrapy as you suggested and found it very useful. However, I've just solved my problem by adding several other fields in my login form.

Answer (score 0):

If You use Scrapy 1.0.4 you get the error:

ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.spiders.init` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders.init` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider

It can be corrected changing the first line

"from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider"

in

from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider

ResearchGate has changed the Login Page: now the correct url is

https://www.researchgate.net/application.Login.html

and has changed "login" with "e-mail" and any other thing in login page.

In any case I always get the usual error:

** [researchgatespider] DEBUG: Wrong credentials **

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You should compare the response.body against some string shown after a successful login. For example "Recommended for you".